# Setting Timeline Speed To 0 Immediately

Tags: unity, c#, animation

I'm currently using a Signal Emitter to call a method that "stops" my Timeline by setting the speed to 0.
Then I wait for player input to go through some dialogue and then continue the Timeline by setting its speed to 1.

```
public void StopTimeline()
    {
        director.playableGraph.GetRootPlayable(0).SetSpeed(0);
        StartCoroutine(GameEngine.Instance.DialogueManager.HandleCutsceneDialogue());
    }
```

The Signal Emitter is calling the method to stop the timeline at the 200 marker, but I'm getting varied results of where it actually stops. In this example, it stopped halfway between 200 & 201.

[image]

Because of this, my characters briefly continue animating for a moment after the 200 mark when they shouldn't be animating yet.

Is there anyway to guarantee the Timeline stopping (speed 0) immediately at the 200 mark like I want?

An obvious work around would simply be to not animate my characters until the 201 mark, but because I'm getting varied results, I'm worried that sometimes my Timeline ***still*** won't stop in time.

I'd like for my cutscene to look the same every time.
What is the best way to ensure my Timeline stays consistent?
Is using a Signal Emitter the best way to "stop" (set the speed to 0) the Timeline?

Comment: I have encountered the same issue when calling the `Pause()` function rather than setting the speed to 0. I've noticed that the Timeline may take longer than 1 or 2 frames to stop if the game is currently sped up (`Time.timeScale` > 1). I haven't found a good solution yet.

Comment: Looks like this is a known quirk of the Timeline, the cause being that signals are evaluated at the end of a rendered frame. See [threads about this on the Unity forums](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+timeline+signal+lag+site:forum.unity.com)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I find solace knowing I'm not the only person who's having this issue. I asked on the Unity forums as well and another User had this to say: "The reason is probably that timeline is updating using Time.time, which would not perfectly match to each frame (= 0.016(s) in 60fps, depend on your setting)." Though, I can't say for certain if they are correct.

Comment: That being said, I find it hard to believe that using a Signal Emitter is the ***only*** way to pause your Timeline. Since Timeline has been around for so long and is really popular, I'd imagine the issue would be more widespread if that was the case.

Comment: Their comment about Time.time is saying the same thing as I did in a different way - the signals are evaluated at the end of a rendered frame, which often doesn't correspond exactly to a timeline frame. You can probably also pause with scripted tracks but I haven't dug into it yet.